# Swift Stripe Connect how to implement account creation

Tags: swift, firebase, stripe-payments

I'm seriously struggling to create a **Stripe Connect** account from my IOS Application using swift and firebase. I can't seem to find any documentation on how this would be possible. I creating an app which allows users to do jobs for each other which of course means pay each other. How can I implement this in my app?

Comment: Are you looking for these docs? https://stripe.dev/stripe-ios/docs/

Comment: Also here the API reference: https://stripe.com/docs/api

Comment: @OlivierKrull i'm looking for documentation that shows how to implement Stripe Connect in IOS to allow user to user payments i can only find web documentation and examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think onboarding users is the biggest difficulty in iOS because(as far as I know) their are only two ways to do this. One, is to use Stripe Onboarding which requires you to take your user to a link where stripe onboards for you. The other, option is building out your own UI flow to manually collect all the information yourself and update their account through the Stripe API.

However, creating an account is simple. Here is an example of it implemented in Node.js!

```
stripe.accounts.create(
    {
      type: 'standard',
      country: 'US',
      email: email,
      requested_capabilities: [
        'card_payments',
        'transfers',
      ],
    },
      function(err, account) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("Couldn't create stripe account: " + err)
          reject(err)
      }

      console.log("ACCOUNT: " + account.id)
      response.body = {success: account.id}
      return res.send(response)
    }
);
```

stripe.dev/stripe-ios/docs